# Linux Apache2 giving error for non existing php file when it does

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

Right now i am using a VPS with Ubuntu 14 and apache2 installed.

I transfered my website from the old hosting to the new one and i started to receive some very strange problems.

Here you can see more info about the PHP version i have and modules:
http://www.crankpost.com/phpinfo.php

This is what i have in the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^crankpost.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.crankpost.com/$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^home mhome.php
 RewriteRule ^checklogin clogin.php 
 RewriteRule ^login login.php  
 RewriteRule ^logout log-out.php 
 RewriteRule ^registration createacc.php  
 RewriteRule ^create-account register.php  
 RewriteRule ^confirm-email=([^/.]+)?$ activateacc.php?id=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^profile=([^/.]+)?$ member.php?id=$1 [L]
```

There is very strange problem.
When i try to open this URL: http://www.crankpost.com/post.php the server gives me error that this file is not open when actually this file exists.

He is in the same directory like index.php, somehow it's giving me error that this file is not existing when actually it exists.

Where can be the problem, can you help me guys?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This could be file permissions - on the folder and on the file. You must ensure that your Apache user - by default, `www-data` - has access. You can use 755 for PHP files and 644 for pretty much everything else.

If you are not familar with file permissions but are using something like FileZilla or WinSCP, then locate the file and the parent folder(s) starting from your document root and make sure that:

- The owning user has Read, Write and Execute permissions.
- The user's group and "Everyone else" has Read permissions.

Depending on your PHP setup, the folders dont need the Executable bit.

But basically, whenever Apache reports that a file does not exist whilst it actually does, its very likely a file-permisison related issue. PHP only needs Read and soemtimes Execute permission on files, but always Execute permissions on the folders it has to traverse.

Hope it helped.

Comment: AFAIK the fact that a directory needs to be executable is a Linux/Unix thing and has nothing whatsoever to do with php setup?

Comment: @fvu it very well does have to do. The various flags define the behavior by which a file may be accessed by an application - like PHP. if PHP can not read a file, because the user it runs as doesn't, then it will fail too.

Comment: @fvu: There is a configuration option called [xbithack](http://php.net/manual/en/apache.configuration.php) which configures the php parser to treat only files with the executable bit set as php source files. The advantage is that _any_ file which is executable is treated as a php source file, regardless of the extension.

Comment: I have the same file rights on post.php like in index.php and they are 644. The index.php file is opening in normal, but the post.php somehow does not want.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg he's talking about *directories*, hence my scepticism - just try what happens if you remove the x bit on a directory (directory and contained files become inaccessible)

Comment: @IngwiePhoenix the xbithack description says "Parse ***files*** with executable bit set as PHP regardless of their file ending.", in your answer you talk about folders.